# Regexp Field with accents and Whitespaces

Tags: regex

I am creating a regular expression to validate a Name-Lastname field. With next code I only can validate a field without accents:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\s+|-)[a-zA-Z]+)*$");
```

How do I allow accents to my city field? (for example: John Solá)

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [:alpha:] character class:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[:alpha:]+(?:(?:\\s+|-)[:alpha:]+)*$");
```

EDIT: Inserted extra backslash, and removed double-braces. However it is noted that some Regex engines allow named character classes with the double-brace. For example, to match spaces and [:alpha:] in ruby, one would do /[ [:alpha:]]+/.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works but there were some syntactic mistakes. Finally I used: Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[:alpha:]+(?:(?:\\s+|-)[:alpha:]+)*$");